# Terraform wants to re-apply aws_ecs_service each time I do a "terraform apply"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs

I am trying to setup an AWS ECS Service via Terraform.

The ECS instance (FARGATE) runs an openldap docker container.

I have got everything working now, the ECS cluster / service / tasks are created properly.

I expected that after doing a

```
terraform apply
```

and after everything is up and running, the next <kbd>terraform apply</kbd> call would simply do nothing because nothing has changed.

But doing a <kbd>terraform apply</kbd> again, Terraform wants to destroy the service (and its connected task) and then wants to create a new service with a new task.

Why does it do that?

These are the Terraform definitions:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "openldap" {
  name            = "openldap"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster_ldap.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.openldap.arn
  desired_count   = 1

  network_configuration {
    subnets = [aws_subnet.sn-public-access.id]
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.secgrp-public-access.id]
    assign_public_ip = true 
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "openldap" {
  family = "openldap-task-definition"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  cpu       = 512
  memory    = 1024
  execution_role_arn    = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn

  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name      = "openldap"
      image     = "public.ecr.aws/bitnami/openldap:2.6.7"
      cpu       = 512
      memory    = 1024
      essential = true
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 1389
          hostPort      = 1389
        },
        {
          containerPort = 1636
          hostPort      = 1636
        }
      ]
      environment = [
        { name = "LDAP_PORT_NUMBER", value = "1389" },
        { name = "LDAP_ROOT", value = "dc=example,dc=com"},
        { name = "LDAP_ADMIN_USERNAME", value = "admin" },
        { name = "LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD_FILE", value = "/openldap/ldap_admin_password.txt" },
        { name = "LDAP_CUSTOM_LDIF_DIR", value = "/openldap/ldif" },
        { name = "BITNAMI_DEBUG", value = "yes" },
        { name = "LDAP_TLS_CERT_FILE", value = "/openldap/certs/ldapserver-cert.pem" },
        { name = "LDAP_TLS_KEY_FILE", value = "/openldap/certs/ldapserver-key.pem" },
        { name = "LDAP_TLS_CA_FILE" , value = "/openldap/certs/ldapserver-cacerts.pem" },
        { name = "LDAP_ENABLE_TLS", value = "yes" },
        { name = "LDAP_ENABLE_RQUIRE_TLS", value = "no" },
        { name = "LDAP_LDAPS_PORT_NUMBER", value = "1636" }
      ]      
      logConfiguration = {
        logDriver = "awslogs"
        options = {
          awslogs-group = "cwlg-ecs-ldap"
          awslogs-stream-prefix = "openldap"
          awslogs-region = "${var.region}"
        }
      }
      mountPoints = [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "openldap",
          "containerPath": "/openldap"
        }
      ]
    }
  ])

 volume {
    name = "openldap"

    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id          = aws_efs_file_system.sandbox-efs.id
      root_directory          = "ldap/"
      transit_encryption      = "ENABLED"
      transit_encryption_port = 2049
    }
  }

  runtime_platform {
    operating_system_family = "LINUX"
    cpu_architecture        = "X86_64"
  }
}
```

And this is the output of second <kbd>terraform apply</kbd> call:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_ecs_service.openldap must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_ecs_service" "openldap" {
      - health_check_grace_period_seconds  = 0 -> null
      ~ iam_role                           = "/aws-service-role/ecs.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForECS" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                                 = "arn:aws:ecs:eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:service/ecs_cluster_ldap/openldap" -> (known after apply)
      + launch_type                        = (known after apply)
        name                               = "openldap"
      ~ platform_version                   = "LATEST" -> (known after apply)
      - propagate_tags                     = "NONE" -> null
      - tags                               = {} -> null
      ~ triggers                           = {} -> (known after apply)
        # (10 unchanged attributes hidden)

      - capacity_provider_strategy { # forces replacement
          - base              = 1 -> null
          - capacity_provider = "FARGATE" -> null
          - weight            = 100 -> null
        }

      - deployment_circuit_breaker {
          - enable   = false -> null
          - rollback = false -> null
        }

      - deployment_controller {
          - type = "ECS" -> null
        }

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

Comment: There are a lot of settings it seems to want to reset to `null`. Are you using the latest version of the AWS Terraform provider? It sort of looks like you are using a really old version that doesn't know how to handle some of the newer features of ECS.

Comment: It wants to set them to null because it thinks it has to destroy the old service. The question is why it thinks so as in my Terraform code nothing has changed between call#1 and call#2

Comment: I think I see what the issue is. I think you have modified the ECS Service's attributes through the AWS console or something. In AWS the ECS service has a capacity provider configuration, but in your Terraform it does not have that. The Terraform plan says removing the capacity provider is triggering the service replacement. All those attributes it is changing to `null` are things you do not have defined in the Terraform code.

Comment: I don't think you are right. All the configuration items I haven't set explicitly in Terraform are obviously optional then. Otherwise Terraform wouldn't have been able to create everything in the first place. If I do not explicitly change these items in the TF code, they are still optional in the second call, thus TF should simply ignore them (again).

Comment: If they were optional, but then you changed those settings to something other than the optional/default value in the AWS web console, then the next time you run Terraform it is going to try changing them all back to the default value, because you didn't update your Terraform code to reflect the values you changed in the AWS web console.

Comment: I did not do anything in the AWS console. I am using Terraform to not use the console. If I did, I would have told it here. It was just two subsequent TF calls with no manual action in between.

Answer (score 1):

The Terraform Apply output is useful for debugging why a resource will be recreated. Look out for any lines with the comment `# forces replacement`. This is Terraform telling you which attribute is out of sync and requires the resource to be recreated in order to bring it in sync.

In your case, it is the `capacity_provider_strategy`. Whilst you do not specify it in your definition, under the hood many resources assume default values.

Your `aws_ecs_service` resource definition should ideally either specify the `launch_type` or `capacity_provider_strategy` arguments. This instructs AWS on the appropriate manner to find capacity for your service.

You specify neither, so I suspect AWS defaults to using Fargate, as reported in your second Terraform apply step:

```
      - capacity_provider_strategy { # forces replacement
          - base              = 1 -> null
          - capacity_provider = "FARGATE" -> null
          - weight            = 100 -> null
        }
```

Given you want to use Fargate, choose one of the two approaches: `launch_type` or `capacity_provider_strategy`. The former is simpler if you don't want to use a mix of deployment targets.

Therefore, try adding the following to your ECS service definition: `launch_type = "FARGATE"`

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "openldap" {
  name            = "openldap"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster_ldap.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.openldap.arn
  desired_count   = 1

  launch_type = "FARGATE"

  network_configuration {
    subnets = [aws_subnet.sn-public-access.id]
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.secgrp-public-access.id]
    assign_public_ip = true 
  }
}
```

The first run of Terraform Apply will likely recreate the service, but subsequent runs will not.

Comment: Thank you for the solution - it works. I cannot upvote your answer as I don't have enough reputation yet :-(

However, what I forgot in my intial post was that I actually did have a capacity provider strategy that was attached to the cluster in which the service runs.'

See my next answer. Do you have any idea why that wasn't enough?

Answer (score 0):

Now what I have is this:

Do I need the default_capacity_provider_strategy after all?

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster_capacity_providers" "capacity_providers" {
  cluster_name = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster_ldap.name

  capacity_providers = ["FARGATE"]

  default_capacity_provider_strategy {
    base              = 1
    weight            = 100
    capacity_provider = "FARGATE"
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "openldap" {
  family = "openldap-task-definition"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  cpu       = 256
  memory    = 512
  execution_role_arn    = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.arn

  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      name      = "openldap"
      image     = "public.ecr.aws/bitnami/openldap:2.6.7"
      essential = true
      portMappings = [
        {
          containerPort = 1389
          hostPort      = 1389
        },
        {
          containerPort = 1636
          hostPort      = 1636
        }
      ]
      environment = [
        { name = "LDAP_PORT_NUMBER", value = "1389" },
        { name = "LDAP_ROOT", value = "dc=example,dc=com"},
        { name = "LDAP_ADMIN_USERNAME", value = "admin" },
        { name = "LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD_FILE", value = "/openldap/ldap_admin_password.txt" },
        { name = "LDAP_CUSTOM_LDIF_DIR", value = "/openldap/ldif" },
        { name = "BITNAMI_DEBUG", value = "yes" },
        { name = "LDAP_TLS_CERT_FILE", value = "/openldap/certs/ldapserver-cert.pem" },
        { name = "LDAP_TLS_KEY_FILE", value = "/openldap/certs/ldapserver-key.pem" },
        { name = "LDAP_TLS_CA_FILE" , value = "/openldap/certs/ldapserver-cacerts.pem" },
        { name = "LDAP_ENABLE_TLS", value = "yes" },
        { name = "LDAP_ENABLE_REQUIRE_TLS", value = "no" },
        { name = "LDAP_LDAPS_PORT_NUMBER", value = "1636" }
      ]      
      logConfiguration = {
        logDriver = "awslogs"
        options = {
          awslogs-group = "cwlg-ecs-ldap"
          awslogs-stream-prefix = "openldap"
          awslogs-region = "${var.region}"
        }
      }
      mountPoints = [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "openldap",
          "containerPath": "/openldap"
        }
      ]
    }
  ])

 volume {
    name = "openldap"

    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id          = aws_efs_file_system.sandbox-efs.id
      root_directory          = "ldap/"
      transit_encryption      = "ENABLED"
      transit_encryption_port = 2049
    }
  }

  runtime_platform {
    operating_system_family = "LINUX"
    cpu_architecture        = "X86_64"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_efs_file_system.sandbox-efs,
    time_sleep.wait_for_ec2-sandbox-linux-01
  ]
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "openldap" {
  name            = "openldap"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.ecs_cluster_ldap.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.openldap.arn
  desired_count   = 1

  launch_type = "FARGATE"

  network_configuration {
    subnets = [aws_subnet.sn-public-access.id]
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.secgrp-public-access.id]
    assign_public_ip = true 
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_execution_role" {
  name = "role-name"
 
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
     "Principal": {
       "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
     },
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Sid": ""
   }
 ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs-task-execution-role-policy-attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_execution_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}
```

Comment: Please do not add updates to your question as answers. Please delete this and update your question if needed.